# BlobSasError when uploading files to Azure IoT Hub with node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm using the Azure IoT Hub node.js device SDK to upload files from a Raspberry Pi.  My intent is to send all files in a given directory to IoT Hub.

When I run my code, initially I get a BlobSasError, but then the files upload successfully. Any ideas what might be causing the errors?  I have tried using different devices as well as changing the SAS keys, but neither has resolved the error.

OS: Raspbian Stretch

Node: v10.16.3

azure-iot-device-mqtt: 1.10.1

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
// add timestamps in front of log messages
require('console-stamp')(console, '[HH:MM:ss.l]');
var mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var clientFromConnectionString = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').clientFromConnectionString;

var connectionString = '<connection string here>';

var client = clientFromConnectionString(connectionString);
console.log('Client connected');


//joining path of directory 
var directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'documents');

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    //listing all files using forEach
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        //console.log(file);
        fs.stat(directoryPath + '/' + file, function (err, stats) {
            const rr = fs.createReadStream(directoryPath + '/' + file);
            client.uploadToBlob(file, rr, stats.size, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error uploading file: ' + err.toString());
                } else {
                    console.log('File uploaded: ' + file);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The following is the console log:

```
[[23:34:36.459]] [LOG]    Client connected
[[23:34:38.865]] [ERROR]  Error uploading file: BlobSasError: Could not obtain blob shared access signature.
[[23:34:38.870]] [ERROR]  Error uploading file: BlobSasError: Could not obtain blob shared access signature.
[[23:34:38.873]] [ERROR]  Error uploading file: BlobSasError: Could not obtain blob shared access signature.
[[23:34:38.876]] [ERROR]  Error uploading file: BlobSasError: Could not obtain blob shared access signature.
[[23:34:38.891]] [ERROR]  Error uploading file: BlobSasError: Could not obtain blob shared access signature.
[[23:34:38.895]] [ERROR]  Error uploading file: BlobSasError: Could not obtain blob shared access signature.
[[23:34:39.590]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155015.jpg
[[23:34:39.813]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155045.jpg
[[23:34:39.896]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155145.jpg
[[23:34:39.916]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155115.jpg
[[23:34:39.951]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155245.jpg
[[23:34:40.051]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155215.jpg
[[23:34:40.053]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155315.jpg
[[23:34:40.055]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155415.jpg
[[23:34:40.133]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155515.jpg
[[23:34:40.157]] [LOG]    File uploaded: Schedule_20190824-155345.jpg
```

Comment: Have you completed the process in the azure portal where you setup the storage container for the IoT Hub file upload? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-file-upload and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-configure-file-upload

Comment: Yes I have done that.  The irony is the files do get successfully uploaded and saved in blob storage.  But those initial errors are still shown.